# Hard Drive not spinning down

Tags: debian, hdparm

I built a NAS with a BananaPi and a SATA hard drive. The OS is Bananian (Debian 8/Jessie). I want to put the harddrive into standby mode using `hdparm -y`.

For some reason this only works, when the hard drive (partition) is not mounted. If i mount it with `-o noatime` and execute `hdparm -y` it does not go into standby.

I also tried different values for `hdparm -B` (127, 128, 254, 255) without any luck.

Looking at iotop and dstat I can see that there is something constantly writing to the harddrive.

`iotop`:

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       3.77 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 1408 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % getty 38400 tty2
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init [2]
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
 1412 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % getty 38400 tty6
```

My guess is that this writing wakes up the hard drive again immediately. The hard drive has a single partition formatted with ext4, and journaling is off.

What could be the cause of this excessive writing? Am I right that this could interfere with standby mode? How should I fix this?

*Edit:*
Regarding NAS, there is currently no software installed (Samba, Apache, ...).
In fact it is a fresh install of Debian without anything else. No software accesses the hard drive, at least not that i am aware of.

Comment: You might want to include some details about how the drive is used as part of the NAS -- e.g., if it is part of a samba share or something. I'm not a samba user, but I'm just guessing a potential culprit is whatever software is making the content "network accessible".  Of course you could test that premise by disabling it to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @goldilocks Its actually not a NAS yet, so there is no software. Added to my question just now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.
I turned up `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` und looked at `dmesg`.

As it turns out ext4lazyinit is still finishing the formatting of the hard drive (inode tables) in the background.

I am going to reformat the drive with `lazy_itable_init=0` to force it to finish.